# Concept of "dead code stripping" in compiler optimization options

Tags: compiler-construction

When i gone through my compiler(starcore,scc) optimization options, i can see one "dead code stripping".

What actually does when this option is enabled?

/Kanu

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The resulting executable will not include any "dead" or unreachable code, because theres no point as it can never be executed.

Comment: at least that is according to code analysis which can not be performed on complex code ( self modifying for example)

Comment: Self-modifying C code is just asking for all kinds of trouble anyway... :)

Answer (score 0):

Dead-code stripping is the process of removing unreferenced code from the executable file. If the code is unreferenced, it must not be used and therefore is not needed in the executable file. Removing dead code reduces the size of your executable and can help reduce paging.